# Change number from negative to positive one.

Tags: java, scala

Very simple task. I can get number with + or -. But have to print only positive variant.

Solved it like this:

```
val absoluteDiff = primary.sum - secondary.sum
println(if (absoluteDiff < 0) absoluteDiff * -1 else absoluteDiff)
```

How can do it simplest?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not familiar with scala, but you could use Math.abs(absoluteDiff).

Comment: `math.abs(a - b);`

Comment: This is not even a Scala question, but a question of rudimentary 4th grade arithmetic :/

Answer (score 5):

Calculate the absolute value using Math.abs:

```
val absoluteDiff = Math.abs(primary.sum - secondary.sum)
```

Description:

The `java.lang.Math.abs(int a)` returns the absolute value of an int value. If the argument is not negative, the argument is returned. If the argument is negative, the negation of the argument is returned.

Source: Math.abs(int) JavaDocs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int-

Comment: Math object is depracated in Scala

Comment: then use `scala.math`. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.package@abs(x:Float):Float

Comment: It's worth noting that both `math.abs(Int.MinValue)` and the Java equivalent are negative, so this doesn't guarantee you'll end up with a non-negative value.

Comment: @Travis Brown - Only for the abs variants that 1) work on long values, and 2) the argument is exactly Long.MIN_VALUE. We should explain the precise case where it might return a negative lest people new to Java or Scala get confused notions of how these functions work.

Answer (score -5):

A more simple way could be to square the difference and take the square-root of the outcome.

e.g.: -2 becomes 4 and then 2 .

I guess the Math.abs() does quite the same.

Comment: Why on earth would you do that? It's slow,/expensive and prone to rounding /overflow issues for large values.  I'm pretty sure `abs` will do the  equivalent of `if (x<0) -x else x`

Comment: Well, just showing more options. No question, it's expensive. By the way - do you know how abs() works?

Comment: Efficient abs functions work not by squaring and then square rooting, I tell you that much.

Comment: @Daddelbob, yes, I do: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Math.java#Math.abs%28int%29

Comment: The proof is in the pudding, or I'd rather say, the grepcode link ;) Nice one @Daddelbob